# How can I run this function when it can work on CMD

Tags: haskell, declaration

```
module Examples where 
   import System.Random
   import Data.List
   cars = ["Ferrari", "Audi", "Honda","McLaren","Merc"]
   cmp (x1,y1) (x2,y2) = compare y1 y2
   [car | (car, n) <- sortBy cmp(zip cars (randoms (mkStdGen 123456) :: [Int]))]
```

I keep getting this error:

Parse error: module header, import declaration
or top-level declaration expected.
|
7 |     [car | (car, n) <- sortBy cmp(zip cars (randoms (mkStdGen 123456) :: [Int]))]
|     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
:reload

Does anyone have any idea for me to fix this so this function can run

Comment: You write an expression at top level. that does not make much sense. You can define a `main` that prints the result for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list comprehension is not a function, it is an expression defined at the top level, which doesn't make much sense. You can define a `main` that prints the result, for example:

```
module Examples where 
  import System.Random
  import Data.List
  
  cars :: [String]
  cars = ["Ferrari", "Audi", "Honda","McLaren","Merc"]
  
  cmp :: Ord b => (a, b) -> (a, b) -> Ordering
  cmp (x1,y1) (x2,y2) = compare y1 y2

  main :: IO ()   
  main = print [car | (car, n) <- sortBy cmp(zip cars (randoms (mkStdGen 123456) :: [Int]))]
```